# Running Python from a virtualenv with Apache/mod_wsgi, on Windows

Tags: python, apache, wamp, virtualenv, wampserver

I'm trying to set up WAMP server. I've got Apache working correctly, and I've installed mod_wsgi without a hitch.

Problem is, I'm using virtual environments (using virtualenv) for my projects. So obviously, mod_wsgi is having problems locating my installation of Django.

I'm trying to understand how I can get mod_wsgi to work well with the virtualenvs. The documentation seems to think this isn't possible:

> Note that the WSGIPythonHome directive can only be used on UNIX systems and is not available on Windows systems. This is because on Windows systems the location of the Python DLL seems to be what dictates where Python will look for the Python library files. It is not known at this point how one could create a distinct baseline environment independent of the main Python installation on Windows.

From here: [mod_wsgi + virtualenv docs](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments).

Does anyone have some idea on how to make this work?

Comment: That comment about WSGIPythonHome on Windows is actually wrong. The restriction was lifted, possibly in mod_wsgi 3.X (not sure). The comment has been removed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can activate the environment programmatically from Python adding this to your .wsgi file before importing anything else.

From [virtualenv's docs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv):

> Sometimes you can't or don't want to
>   use the Python interpreter created by
>   the virtualenv. For instance, in a
>   mod_python or mod_wsgi environment,
>   there is only one interpreter.
>
> Luckily, it's easy. You must use the
>   custom Python interpreter to install
>   libraries. But to use libraries, you
>   just have to be sure the path is
>   correct. A script is available to
>   correct the path. You can setup the
>   environment like:
>
> ```
> activate_this = '/path/to/env/bin/activate_this.py'
> execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
> ```
>
> This will change sys.path and even
>   change sys.prefix, but also allow you
>   to use an existing interpreter. Items
>   in your environment will show up first
>   on sys.path, before global items.
>   However, this cannot undo the
>   activation of other environments, or
>   modules that have been imported. You
>   shouldn't try to, for instance,
>   activate an environment before a web
>   request; you should activate one
>   environment as early as possible, and
>   not do it again in that process.

Comment: This looks good, I'll try it out. But it looks like that will use the "main" Python interepereter on my system, not the one created using virtualenv, right? This means I can only use one version of Python on my system? (This would only be a minor issue).

Comment: It will use the interpreter mod_wsgi embeds into apache but will make sure sys.path is populated properly with the libraries installed in the virtualenv

Comment: Searchers - you can see this implemented here: http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/ towards the bottom it shows you how to activate and set the path variables in your wsgi.py

Comment: To remove the absolute path, you can also do `activate_this = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/env/bin/activate_this.py'` (assuming your virtual environment is rooted at the same location as your WSGI file.