# Import Error: No module named Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, apache2, wsgi

I am getting 500 internal server error when running my server with Flask,apache2, and Python 3.4.2.

At first I installed Flask without creating virtual environment, so I thought that that could be a reason. However, I later created virtual environment for my app using:

```
python3.4 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
(venv) pip3 install Flask
```

I checked by running my app using python3 **__init.py** and it was working on local.
Then I reloaded my apache2 server, and still getting the same error. Please see below output from error log file:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=25667): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=25667): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 11, in <module>
from XYZ import app as application
File "/var/www/FlaskApp/XYZ/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from flask import Flask, render_template
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Any suggestions how to fix it?

FlaskApp.conf file in the etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName xyz.com

ServerAlias www.xyz.com

ServerAdmin contact@xyz.com
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
<Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/XYZ/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/XYZ/static
<Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/XYZ/static/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's line from apache2 error log file:

```
AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

It looks like mod_wsgi is trying to use 2.7.8 as opposed to 3.4. How do I fix that?

Comment: I checked in my flaskapp folder - there is folder named venv that has lib folder which has flask in it. Why is it not working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Python from a virtualenv with Apache/mod\_wsgi, on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614121/running-python-from-a-virtualenv-with-apache-mod-wsgi-on-windows)

Comment: I noticed interesting thing - when I check virtual environment folder there is no Flask under site-packages even though it shows as if it got installed when I do pip3 install Flask. I will try using pip.

Comment: I tried using pip - this time venv has flask in it but still getting the same error - 500 and no flask module in apache2 log file.

Comment: Delete the virtual environment made using Python 3.x.x and make one with Pyhton 2.x.x

Comment: I wanted to add more color - when I create virtual environment I am not getting message: "New python executable in venv/bin/python". When I used Python 2.x I has such message, I am not sure if it's just Python 3.4 thing but thought it might help with figuring out what happens.

Comment: I tried to do everything from scratch again - does not work.

Comment: I am thinking of using activate_this.py script. I am not familiar with it - I read docs on it but still confused how to generate activate_this.py file?

Comment: My flaskapp.wsgi file looks as follows:

Comment: #! /usr/bin/python3.4

    import sys 
    import logging

    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr) 
    sys.path.insert(0,"var/www/FlaskApp")

    from XYZ import app as application

    application.secret_key = "secret"

Comment: I checked bin folder in /var/www/FlaskApp/XYZ/venv/bin/activate_this.py - there is no file called activate_this.py there, there is file called activate. How do I fix that?

Comment: On flask irc channel I was told that web server (mod-wsgi) needs to know to use specific virtual environment as in original configuration it uses python 2.7. I tried to fix it by adding the WSGIPythonHome /path/to/my/virt/env to global apache2.conf file but it does not work either. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: As a background, the reason I am trying to use python 3.4 is because my code in it.

Comment: What operating system are you running and How was Apache installed? I guess apache's user isn't able to see the virtualenv. But first answer the two questions.

Comment: 1. I am using Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: 2. sudo apt-get install apache2

Comment: correction - Ubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I finally solved it!
I added the following line of code to FlaskApp.conf file located in etc/apache2/sites-available:

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/FlaskApp/XYZ/venv/:/var/www/FlaskApp/XYZ/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

This line should go ahead of VirtualHost!

Then I restarted apache and got my site working, except only with www, non-www does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I changed my xx.wsgi from using execfile() to using exec(). Here is what it looks like when it finally worked.

```
activate_this = '/opt/flask/project_name/py3venv/bin/activate_this.py'
exec(open(activate_this).read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/flask/project_name')

from project_app_name import app as application
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you put in activate_this.py

Comment: It was generated by virtualenv when I executed these command:
"cd /opt/flask/bionxws" and 
"virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 p3venv"

Answer (score 0):

`mod_wsgi` likely doesn't know about your virtualenv, and simply needs to be told to use that rather than the default system environment.

[This info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-a-virtualenv) in the Django docs should help.

If it doesn't, please post your `flaskapp.wsgi` and `httpd.conf` files.

Comment: flaskapp.wsgi looks as follows:

Comment: #! /usr/bin/python3.4

import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"var/www/FlaskApp")

from XYZ import app as application

application.secret_key = "secret" `code`

Comment: there is no httpd.conf file - I checked apache2 folder. I posted FlaskApp.conf file if that helps. Thank you for looking into it!

Comment: Neither it's in the apache2 folder. I will create it and add the following lines:

Comment: WSGIPythonHome /path/to/my/virt/env

Comment: WSGIPythonPath /var/www/virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages

Comment: PythonHome will have the same path as PythonPath