# Deploying flask app to Apache shared hosting

Tags: python, apache, deployment, flask, cgi

I am trying to deploy a simple flask application in the Apache shared hosting server.

I am not sure what is wrong here.

I am stuck at the `.cgi` file for now.

The flask app - hello.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The myapp.cgi file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python  

import os
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from hello import app


os.environ['SERVER_NAME'] = '127.0.0.1'
os.environ['SERVER_PORT'] = '5000'
os.environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET'
os.environ['PATH_INFO'] = ""

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

Both the files are placed in the `/home/username/public_html/cgi-bin` directory

The same `cgi-bin` has the directory named `myenv` - it's a `virtualenv` I have created. The `virtualenv` is active.

Now,

I navigate to the cgi-bin directory and run -

```
 python hello.py
```

I get this :

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

So this is fine. Now I am running the myapp.cgi file:

```
python myapp.cgi
```

I get this :

```
Status: 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 251
Location: http://127.0.0.1:5000/

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/">http://127.0.0.1:5000/</a>.  If not click the link.
```

How can I make this status as 200 OK,
Please suggest.

Thanks!

Comment: @Burhan : can you please suggest me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make few changes in the `.cgi` file. Below is the final file.

```
import os
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from hello import app


CGIHandler().run(app)
```

and added these lines in my `hello.py` file:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/username/public_html/cgi-bin/myenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
```

Refer this - https://medium.com/@mohdejazsiddiqui/deploy-flask-app-in-apache-shared-hosting-5b3c82c8fd5e

Comment: link is dead :(

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă: Updated the new link. You can check [here](https://medium.com/@mohdejazsiddiqui/deploy-flask-app-in-apache-shared-hosting-5b3c82c8fd5e)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 big misunderstandings about how apache works with flask with the help of cgi.

1. Apache uses the system directorys for the python interpreter. You can in fact change the sys.path [Like here descriped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614121/running-python-from-a-virtualenv-with-apache-mod-wsgi-on-windows). But that is far from ideal.
2. you don't have to call python for your cgi file. The Server will do that when you did your config correctly

[in the cgi doc of flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/cgi/) are some ways how you get the server to work with the cgi file.

Since you say you want it to upload at shared hosting writing a `.htaccess` file for your needs would be the most promesing way, since most of those services only allow you to work from your public dircectory. In this case you also have to use a shared hoster where python is on the server or be willed to install python with all the packages you need for you, since you can't install any packages by yourself.

You could try the [changing of the interpreter path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614121/running-python-from-a-virtualenv-with-apache-mod-wsgi-on-windows), but i have no experience if that would work on shared hosting.